# Calculating last 5 items for each row of the table

Tags: powerbi, dax

Power BI Dax question:

I have the following table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT2bM.png)

How can i have a running calculation using a measure which sums the 5 previous rows from "Status" column?
See the photo below for the idea in excel

[Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY758.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You Time column holds all same date. So how order order data to define last 5 rows? You must have some other column like - ID or Index to apply the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra column and do a top5 filter.

```
SumStatusLast5 = 
VAR curDate = yourTable['TIME']
VAR allRowsBefore = FILTER(yourTable, curDate >= yourTable['TIME'])
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM[Status], TOPN(5, allRowsBefore, yourTable['TIME']))
```

In the first step I get the curDate of the row
In the second step I get all rows where the date is equal or smaller
In the last step, I take the top5 of those returned rows and sum them together

Comment: Thanks, this does work. I was originally looking to do this inside a measure, but this works too